# Как обратиться в свойству класса зная название этого свойства?

Tags: c++

Я могу обратиться так :

```
current_average_speed_element->in_bytes
```

Как мне обратиться так:

```
string myvar = "in_bytes";
//...
current_average_speed_element->myvar;
```

Весь код целиком:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class map_element {
   public:
   map_element()
   : in_bytes(0){
   }
   void set(int val){in_bytes=val;}
   uint64_t in_bytes;
};

int main() 
{
    vector<map_element> current_element;
    current_element.resize(1);
    current_element[0].set(199999);    


    map_element* current_average_speed_element;
    current_average_speed_element = &current_element[0];
    string myvar = "in_bytes";
    //cout << "OUT RESULT: " << current_average_speed_element->{myvar} <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код вашего класса и как вы с этим классом работаете.

Comment: А зачем вам это? C++ — не PHP и не Javascript, у него другие выразительные средства. Какую проблему вы хотите решить при помощи обращения по имени?

Comment: Дело в том, что есть несколько характеристик с фиксированными значениями:
`protocol: tcp|udp|....
direction: incoming|outcoming
flags: SYN|ACK|...`
под каждое значение каждой хар-ки есть свой  каунтер: 
`element->tcp_syn_incoming`...
так вот чтобы не перебирать все возможные вариант, я планировать генерить вот этот самый `key = tcp_syn_incoming`

Comment: , тк хакартеристики задают через json и могу быть различными: tcp_syn_incoming, tcp_ack_incoming, tcp_fin_incoming... или их вообще не может быть, иначе получается большое нагромаждение if-ов и case-ов

Comment: _свой каунтер: element->tcp_syn_incoming_ - это переменная какого типа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То что вы пытаетесь сделать называется [Рефлексией(отражением)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), но в C++ рефлексия не поддерживается.

Есть возможность обращения по указателю на член класса, но не по его имени в строке

Пример с указателем

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    int member;
};

using a_member = int A::*;

int main() {
    a_member m = &A::member; // получаем указатель на член класса
    //...
    A* a = new A();
    a->member = 42;
    // обращаемся по указателю
    cout << (a->*m) << endl;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/dWrMkj)

На основе этого можно создать словарь(map) "имя"->"указатель"

Минимальная реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {
    int first;
    int second;
};

using member_ptr = int A::*;

using member_map = std::unordered_map<std::string, member_ptr>;

static member_map Amap = {
    {"first",  &A::first},
    {"second", &A::second}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.*(Amap["first" ]) = 42;
    a.*(Amap["second"]) = 24;
    std::cout << a.first  << std::endl
              << a.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/JVtKfh)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не решает проблему, если я все правильно понял,  этот случай эквивалентен случаю прямого обращения по свойству, думаю все же придется if-ами отбиваться.

Comment: @fizikst теоретически можно создать словарь(map) "имя"-"указатель" и использовать его для обращения `obj->*(map[name])` но как то "страшновато" выглядит данная конструкция

Comment: @fizikst, не совсем эквивалентен: обычно код получается компактнее и — при большом размере таблицы — понятнее, чем разросшиеся блоки `if` и `switch`. Инициализация таблицы просто инкапсулируется в функцию с говорящим названием и упрятывается с глаз долой, упрощая оставшийся код. Надо смотреть, становится ли код проще в Вашем конкретном случае.

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин просто код с таблицой был добавлен _после_ этого комментария) изначально в ответе было только про указатель